# jquery events effecting wrong elements

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-ui-sortable, addclass

```
http://s199881165.onlinehome.us/transfem/sortable%20test/sortable2.php
```

So I am working on a video-site UI that has draggable / droppable / sortable (jquery) tiles that link to certain videos. As you can see when you mouse over them they all go crazy...

What should happen -- and what I was trying to code -- is for a mouseover on one box to trigger the add/remove class for ONE that tile (div).

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: please share the code instead of just adding a url

Comment: You want to add/remove the class `boxxy` from the second entry when you move mouse over first entry

Comment: Here it is all separated in a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NhFDP/). You really shouldn't have so many `<script>` tags in the HTML. We could probably clean this up into a few lines of JavaScript and put it in the `<head>` tag but you'll want to modify your HTML a bit to make it easier. Think of using classes over ids and just be specific with relativity in your jQuery selectors. Also I'm not sure what's going on in your website but in the jsfiddle demo it is working exactly as you want. Try cleaning up your code and consolidating all JavaScript at the top of your document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what I did in the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NhFDP/1/) was add the class `box` to each div you are trying to show. It lets you clean up the JavaScript to this:

HTML:

```
<div id="timeline">
    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default" id="thelistitemyo"><div id="theone1" class="box boxxySTILL" style="background-image: url(http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/435/247/435247991_640.jpg);" width="100%"></div><span class="spannin">Demo 4</span><div class="desrippor">Mnulla adipiscing risus purus, eu tempus felis. Morbi sit amet lectus felis, mattis venenatis augue. Praesent pretium egestas mauris eget scelerisque. Etiam euismod libero ac eros commodo interdum. Curabitur pulvinar ante nec diam euismod vestibulum. Nam tincidunt diam quis est facilisis varius. Aliquam consequat erat sed enim facilisis eget sollicitudin felis laoreet. Nulla turpis magna, fermentum id    ornare ut, bibendum at libero. Etiam dapibus congue enim sit amet suscipit. Donec ut purus ut nisi laoreet porta. Donec mattis, lectus sit amet semper tincidunt, ligula erat semper erat, a tincidunt est odio in lacus. Proin nisl ipsum, rhoncus tincidunt mattis at, blandit eget lacus. Ut fringilla hendrerit vulputate. Sed at neque et nibh dignissim adipiscing. Nulla consequat velit ut ante tristique lacinia. Fusce in nulla vel augue sagittis faucibus.</div></li>

        <li class="ui-state-default" id="thelistitemyo"><div id="theone2" class="box boxxySTILL" style="background-image: url(http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/343/179/343179766_640.jpg);" width="100%"></div><span class="spannin">Mixtape 3sec</span><div class="desrippor">Mnulla adipiscing risus purus, eu tempus felis. Morbi sit amet lectus felis, mattis venenatis augue. Praesent pretium egestas mauris eget scelerisque. Etiam euismod libero ac eros commodo interdum. Curabitur pulvinar ante nec diam euismod vestibulum. Nam tincidunt diam quis est facilisis varius. Aliquam consequat erat sed enim facilisis eget sollicitudin felis laoreet. Nulla turpis magna, fermentum id  ornare ut, bibendum at libero. Etiam dapibus congue enim sit amet suscipit. Donec ut purus ut nisi laoreet porta. Donec mattis, lectus sit amet semper tincidunt, ligula erat semper erat, a tincidunt est odio in lacus. Proin nisl ipsum, rhoncus tincidunt mattis at, blandit eget lacus. Ut fringilla hendrerit vulputate. Sed at neque et nibh dignissim adipiscing. Nulla consequat velit ut ante tristique lacinia. Fusce in nulla vel augue sagittis faucibus.</div></li>

        <li class="ui-state-default" id="thelistitemyo"><div id="theone3" class="box boxxySTILL" style="background-image: url(http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/398/394/398394157_640.jpg);" width="100%"></div><span class="spannin">begun - san francisco</span><div class="desrippor">Mnulla adipiscing risus purus, eu tempus felis. Morbi sit amet lectus felis, mattis venenatis augue. Praesent pretium egestas mauris eget scelerisque. Etiam euismod libero ac eros commodo interdum. Curabitur pulvinar ante nec diam euismod vestibulum. Nam tincidunt diam quis est facilisis varius. Aliquam consequat erat sed enim facilisis eget sollicitudin felis laoreet. Nulla turpis magna, fermentum id     ornare ut, bibendum at libero. Etiam dapibus congue enim sit amet suscipit. Donec ut purus ut nisi laoreet porta. Donec mattis, lectus sit amet semper tincidunt, ligula erat semper erat, a tincidunt est odio in lacus. Proin nisl ipsum, rhoncus tincidunt mattis at, blandit eget lacus. Ut fringilla hendrerit vulputate. Sed at neque et nibh dignissim adipiscing. Nulla consequat velit ut ante tristique lacinia. Fusce in nulla vel augue sagittis faucibus.</div></li>

        <li class="ui-state-default" id="thelistitemyo"><div id="theone4" class="box boxxySTILL" style="background-image: url(http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/435/248/435248805_640.jpg);" width="100%"></div><span class="spannin">Demo 5</span><div class="desrippor">Mnulla adipiscing risus purus, eu tempus felis. Morbi sit amet lectus felis, mattis venenatis augue. Praesent pretium egestas mauris eget scelerisque. Etiam euismod libero ac eros commodo interdum. Curabitur pulvinar ante nec diam euismod vestibulum. Nam tincidunt diam quis est facilisis varius. Aliquam consequat erat sed enim facilisis eget sollicitudin felis laoreet. Nulla turpis magna, fermentum id    ornare ut, bibendum at libero. Etiam dapibus congue enim sit amet suscipit. Donec ut purus ut nisi laoreet porta. Donec mattis, lectus sit amet semper tincidunt, ligula erat semper erat, a tincidunt est odio in lacus. Proin nisl ipsum, rhoncus tincidunt mattis at, blandit eget lacus. Ut fringilla hendrerit vulputate. Sed at neque et nibh dignissim adipiscing. Nulla consequat velit ut ante tristique lacinia. Fusce in nulla vel augue sagittis faucibus.</div></li>

        <li class="ui-state-default" id="thelistitemyo"><div id="theone5" class="box boxxySTILL" style="background-image: url(http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/424/127/424127918_640.jpg);" width="100%"></div><span class="spannin">3 Second Video</span><div class="desrippor">Mnulla adipiscing risus purus, eu tempus felis. Morbi sit amet lectus felis, mattis venenatis augue. Praesent pretium egestas mauris eget scelerisque. Etiam euismod libero ac eros commodo interdum. Curabitur pulvinar ante nec diam euismod vestibulum. Nam tincidunt diam quis est facilisis varius. Aliquam consequat erat sed enim facilisis eget sollicitudin felis laoreet. Nulla turpis magna, fermentum id    ornare ut, bibendum at libero. Etiam dapibus congue enim sit amet suscipit. Donec ut purus ut nisi laoreet porta. Donec mattis, lectus sit amet semper tincidunt, ligula erat semper erat, a tincidunt est odio in lacus. Proin nisl ipsum, rhoncus tincidunt mattis at, blandit eget lacus. Ut fringilla hendrerit vulputate. Sed at neque et nibh dignissim adipiscing. Nulla consequat velit ut ante tristique lacinia. Fusce in nulla vel augue sagittis faucibus.</div></li>

        <li class="ui-state-default" id="thelistitemyo"><div id="theone6" class="box boxxySTILL" style="background-image: url(http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/343/179/343179766_640.jpg);" width="100%"></div><span class="spannin">Mixtape 3sec</span><div class="desrippor">Mnulla adipiscing risus purus, eu tempus felis. Morbi sit amet lectus felis, mattis venenatis augue. Praesent pretium egestas mauris eget scelerisque. Etiam euismod libero ac eros commodo interdum. Curabitur pulvinar ante nec diam euismod vestibulum. Nam tincidunt diam quis est facilisis varius. Aliquam consequat erat sed enim facilisis eget sollicitudin felis laoreet. Nulla turpis magna, fermentum id  ornare ut, bibendum at libero. Etiam dapibus congue enim sit amet suscipit. Donec ut purus ut nisi laoreet porta. Donec mattis, lectus sit amet semper tincidunt, ligula erat semper erat, a tincidunt est odio in lacus. Proin nisl ipsum, rhoncus tincidunt mattis at, blandit eget lacus. Ut fringilla hendrerit vulputate. Sed at neque et nibh dignissim adipiscing. Nulla consequat velit ut ante tristique lacinia. Fusce in nulla vel augue sagittis faucibus.</div></li>

        <li class="ui-state-default" id="thelistitemyo"><div id="theone7" class="box boxxySTILL" style="background-image: url(http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/334/173/334173957_640.jpg);" width="100%"></div><span class="spannin">Down - Time Lapse - 3sec</span><div class="desrippor">Mnulla adipiscing risus purus, eu tempus felis. Morbi sit amet lectus felis, mattis venenatis augue. Praesent pretium egestas mauris eget scelerisque. Etiam euismod libero ac eros commodo interdum. Curabitur pulvinar ante nec diam euismod vestibulum. Nam tincidunt diam quis est facilisis varius. Aliquam consequat erat sed enim facilisis eget sollicitudin felis laoreet. Nulla turpis magna, fermentum id  ornare ut, bibendum at libero. Etiam dapibus congue enim sit amet suscipit. Donec ut purus ut nisi laoreet porta. Donec mattis, lectus sit amet semper tincidunt, ligula erat semper erat, a tincidunt est odio in lacus. Proin nisl ipsum, rhoncus tincidunt mattis at, blandit eget lacus. Ut fringilla hendrerit vulputate. Sed at neque et nibh dignissim adipiscing. Nulla consequat velit ut ante tristique lacinia. Fusce in nulla vel augue sagittis faucibus.</div></li>

        <li class="ui-state-default" id="thelistitemyo"><div id="theone8" class="box boxxySTILL" style="background-image: url(http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/343/179/343179766_640.jpg);" width="100%"></div><span class="spannin">Mixtape 3sec</span><div class="desrippor">Mnulla adipiscing risus purus, eu tempus felis. Morbi sit amet lectus felis, mattis venenatis augue. Praesent pretium egestas mauris eget scelerisque. Etiam euismod libero ac eros commodo interdum. Curabitur pulvinar ante nec diam euismod vestibulum. Nam tincidunt diam quis est facilisis varius. Aliquam consequat erat sed enim facilisis eget sollicitudin felis laoreet. Nulla turpis magna, fermentum id  ornare ut, bibendum at libero. Etiam dapibus congue enim sit amet suscipit. Donec ut purus ut nisi laoreet porta. Donec mattis, lectus sit amet semper tincidunt, ligula erat semper erat, a tincidunt est odio in lacus. Proin nisl ipsum, rhoncus tincidunt mattis at, blandit eget lacus. Ut fringilla hendrerit vulputate. Sed at neque et nibh dignissim adipiscing. Nulla consequat velit ut ante tristique lacinia. Fusce in nulla vel augue sagittis faucibus.</div></li>

        <li class="ui-state-default" id="thelistitemyo"><div id="theone9" class="box boxxySTILL" style="background-image: url(http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/370/039/370039831_640.jpg);" width="100%"></div><span class="spannin">Bravo TV 3sec</span><div class="desrippor">Mnulla adipiscing risus purus, eu tempus felis. Morbi sit amet lectus felis, mattis venenatis augue. Praesent pretium egestas mauris eget scelerisque. Etiam euismod libero ac eros commodo interdum. Curabitur pulvinar ante nec diam euismod vestibulum. Nam tincidunt diam quis est facilisis varius. Aliquam consequat erat sed enim facilisis eget sollicitudin felis laoreet. Nulla turpis magna, fermentum id     ornare ut, bibendum at libero. Etiam dapibus congue enim sit amet suscipit. Donec ut purus ut nisi laoreet porta. Donec mattis, lectus sit amet semper tincidunt, ligula erat semper erat, a tincidunt est odio in lacus. Proin nisl ipsum, rhoncus tincidunt mattis at, blandit eget lacus. Ut fringilla hendrerit vulputate. Sed at neque et nibh dignissim adipiscing. Nulla consequat velit ut ante tristique lacinia. Fusce in nulla vel augue sagittis faucibus.</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function()
{
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable(
    {
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();

    $('#sortable1 li').mouseenter(function()
    {
        $(this).find('.box').removeClass('boxxySTILL', 200, 'linear')
                            .addClass('boxxy', 200, 'linear');
    });

    $('#sortable1 li').mouseleave(function()
    {
        $(this).find('.box').removeClass('boxxy', 200, 'linear')
                            .addClass('boxxySTILL', 200, 'linear');
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you so much! Every one of these little challenges I give myself teaches that much more about javascript, css, etc. Thanks for helping me understand all this amazing nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason is you have the `script` tag as a child of `#sortable1`. Because of this your `$( "#sortable1 li:nth-child(1)" )` selector is not producing the desired result

One possible solution is to try

```
$( "#sortable1 li:eq(1)" )
```

As better solution, I suggest you use something like

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1 > li").hover(function(){
        $(this).next().children('div').removeClass( "boxxySTILL", 200, "linear" ).addClass( "boxxy", 200, "linear" );
    }, function(){
        $(this).next().children('div').removeClass( "boxxy", 200, "linear" ).addClass( "boxxySTILL", 200, "linear" );
    });
});
```

instead of registering handlers for every `li` like this

```
  $(function() {
  $( "#sortable1 li:nth-child(1)" ).mouseenter(function() {

  $( "#theone1" ).removeClass( "boxxySTILL", 200, "linear" ).addClass( "boxxy", 200, "linear" );

});

  $(function() {
  $( "#sortable1 li:nth-child(1)" ).mouseleave(function() {

    $( "#theone1"  ).removeClass( "boxxy", 200, "linear" ).addClass( "boxxySTILL", 200, "linear" );

}); 

  });
});
```